# Loop through relationships Laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach, relationship

Stackoverflow,

What I want to accomplish:

I want to Loop through the database to find all the (Heroes) with their related (Interview). I want to also pull each Interview with it's related (Story) and (Image). So far I can dd($heroes) and I can see the array correctly grab each hero with their interview and each interview has it's associated image and story. How do I loop through this correctly?

**Error**

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /Users/plastics1509moore/Desktop/elephant_gin/resources/views/administration/index.blade.php)
```

This is what I have done:

**Controller:**

```
$heroes = Hero::with('Interview', 'Interview.stories', 'Interview.images')->orderBy('position', 'asc')->get();
```

**Model Relationships:**

**Hero:**

```
public function Interview()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Interview', 'heroInt_id');
}
```

**Interview:**

```
    public function relationships()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Hero');
}
public function stories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\InterviewStory');
}
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\InterviewImage');
}
```

**InterviewImage:**

```
 public function relationships()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Interview');
}
```

**InterviewStory**

```
public function relationships()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Interview');
}
```

**Html:**

**Loop:**

```
    @foreach($heroes as $hero)
       @foreach($hero->Interview as $story)
         <div>{{$story->id}}</div>
        @endforeach    
    @endforeach
```

Comment: What's your problem exactly?

Comment: The error i got with this was that i was providing invalid arguments the foreach loop of the second foreach

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't loop on Interview because this a `hasOne` relationship. What you might want to do is

```
@foreach($heroes as $hero)
   @foreach($hero->interview->stories as $story)
     <div>{{$story->id}}</div>
    @endforeach    
@endforeach
```

Comment: I don't know if Laravel likes the uppercases pretty much... Try to rewrite your relationships with camelCase

Comment: Tried it. Same error unfortunately...I can get the interview...I just cant loop through the interview's relationships.

Comment: Like I told you, you don't loop on interview relationship but on the stories one. Interview is just a hasOne you can't loop on it

Comment: Thats what i was saying... but i realized the issue is that some of the entries didn't have interviews. I added all of the interviews and your code works.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it's not possible to loop because it has `hasOne` relationship?

Comment: Hey! Well a HasOne relationship returns only one element, not a collection. If you loop on the result of a HasOne, you will loop on the attribute of the relationship, not on a model. Is it clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is because not following laravel "assumes". In documentation:

> Additionally, Eloquent assumes that the foreign key should have a
>   value matching the id column of the parent. In other words, Eloquent
>   will look for the value of the user's id column in the user_id column
>   of the Phone record. If you would like the relationship to use a value
>   other than id, you may pass a third argument to the hasOne method
>   specifying your custom key:
>
> `return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`

What is the id of Hero? If it's different than `id`, then you have to add the `local_key` name.

Comment: The id in hero is id. However the foriegn_key inside of interviews is called heroInt_id. This referes to id in hero. The problem wasn't the relationships. It was being able to loop the hero's and their interview and loop through the relations of their interview as well.

Comment: @RickiMoore Well. If you add dd($hero->Interview) what you get?

Comment: It pulls the interview Array...Which is fine. Interview {#290 ▼
  #table: "interviews"
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:4 [▶]
  #original: array:4 [▶]
  #relations: array:2 [▼
    "stories" => Collection {#283 ▶}
    "images" => Collection {#312 ▶}
  ]
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}